# Suppress empty string elements in JAXB ArrayList

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

There solutions to ignore the empty string elements, but in my case I have a Array list which has many empty strings ( Not null ).

So I get lots of empty elements in the generated output.

Thoughts ?

```
@XmlElement
private List<String> fileNumber;
```

This is the output:

```
<fileNumber>25478</fileNumber>
<fileNumber>45875</fileNumber>
<fileNumber></fileNumber>
<fileNumber></fileNumber>
```

I can solve this issue by removing them in the list at the setFileNumber. (Like below)

```
public void setFileNumber(List<String> fileNumber) {
    fileNumber.removeAll(Collections.singleton(""));
    this.fileNumber = fileNumber;
}
```

But is there a solution at JAXB level ? Like nillable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a marshal event call back method for this use case (see:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html#marshalEventCallback).  This method would go on the class with the `fileNumber` property, and your JAXB implementation will call this method before it marshals the object giving you the opportunity to do any necessary clean up.

```
private void beforeMarshal(Marshaller marshaller) {
    fileNumber.removeAll(Collections.singleton(""));
}
```